# I can't see liquidity of a token in my pancakeswap fork. that has already added liquidity on pancakeswap

Tags: fork, pancakeswap

I forked goosedefi frontend from GitHub and added a token in pancakeswap.json file. The added token already been added liquidity on pancakeswap and I use the pancakeswap v2 router. And when I try to swap on my fork with bnb&busd pair, it is showing "insufficient liquidity for this trade". I am using the same pancakeswap router address, or should I add additional liquidity to the token in my fork even if it has already added liquidity in pancakeswap

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the FACTORY address too.